# How do I ignore updates to files deleted in trunk

Tags: svn

Under SVN 1.6.5 we have a repo where the "Trunk" is where we do our main development.

We have a "Production" branch that is our live website code.

When development changes are to be pushed out to the live site we do a range of revisions merge from the trunk to sync the trunk and the branch.

In the "Trunk" we have some project information that we don't really want in the "Production" branch.

I can delete it just fine from the "Production" branch but end up getting tree conflicts when merging revisions that have updates to the deleted files.

I know I can do an "Only Record Revisions" merge but am wondering if there is a simpler way to "Ignore" the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can ignore them, but resolving such conflicts doesn't have to take much time.

First solve the "real" conflicts and make sure that only conflicts caused by deletions in the production branch remain. Then auto-resolve all those remaining from the root of your working copy like this:

```
svn resolve -R --accept=mine-full .
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) to arrange for the relevant "production" branch files/directories to be picked up from a repository location where they are stubbed out instead of from trunk.